# can't get props from parent component inside child component componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component fetching some data from an API and store the data in the state and pass it to child component like this:

```
export default class TourDetailsPage extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tour: ''
        };
      }

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        const name = this.props.match.params.name.replace(/-/g, ' ');
        const res = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/tours?name=${name}`);
        const tour = await res.json();
        this.setState({tour: tour.data.docs[0]});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Container style={{width:'90%'}}>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Row>
                            <Grid.Column width={16} textAlign={"center"}>
                                <TourDetailsHeader
                                    tour={this.state.tour}
                                />
                            </Grid.Column>
                        </Grid.Row>
                    </Grid>
                </Container>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Inside my child component I have two problems, 
One is: I want to receive one of the props(ratingsAverage) inside componentDidMount but got undefined while I am able to receive ratingsAverage inside render() function. 
Another is: Inside my render() function, I can only receive the data which is not an object or an array, when I receive an object and want to access the property of the object, it gives me an error said that can not read that property of undefined. My child component code:
In the child component, 'startLocation' is an object from parent component while I can't access to it's properties.

```
class TourDetailsHeader extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: 0
        };
      }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        const { ratingsAverage } = this.props.tour;
        console.log(ratingsAverage); // output undefined

    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.tour);
        const {name, imageCover, ratingsAverage, duration, startLocation} = this.props.tour;
        return(
            <Fragment>
            <Segment.Group>
                <Segment basic attached="top" style={{ padding: '0' }}>
                    <Image src={`/tours/${imageCover}`} style={eventImageStyle} />
                    <Segment basic style={eventImageTextStyle}>
                        <Item.Group>
                            <Item>
                                <Item.Content>

                                    <Item.Description style={{marginTop: '3%'}}>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.Column width={5}>
                                                <Icon name='plane' size={'big'} color={'green'}/>
                                                {startLocation.description}
                                            </Grid.Column>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Item.Description>
                                </Item.Content>
                            </Item>
                            <Item>

                            </Item>
                        </Item.Group>
                    </Segment>
                </Segment>
            </Segment.Group>
        </Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

I would appreciate it so much if someone could help me with this!

Comment: maybe adding some try catch into componentDidMount  would help you debug that issue  https://www.valentinog.com/blog/await-react/

Comment: Did you check the result of `res.json()`?

Comment: I think it's just erroring out on first render, before your request finishes and sets tour in state. Are you managing any kind of loading state? Console.log() `tour` at the top of TourDetailsHeader

Answer (score 2):

Why you get `ratingsAverage` with `undefined` value in the child component?
In React, the lifecycle of a component is `initiating constructor -> render -> componentDidMount -> componentDidUpdate ->...->componentWillUnmount` ([read more about react lifecycle here](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/)). So in your case, the child component is rendered before you get data from API so `tour` is empty string and `ratingsAverage` is also `undefined`. If you want to receive `tour` props you can see it in `componentDidUpdate` of the child component.
In your case, if you want to use `startLocation.description` you should check whether `startLocation` is existed in props or not. 
Try this:

```js
class TourDetailsHeader extends Component{
    ...
    componentDidUpdate() {
        const { ratingsAverage } = this.props.tour;
        console.log(ratingsAverage);
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.tour);
        const {name, imageCover, ratingsAverage, duration, startLocation} = this.props.tour;
        return(
            ...
              <Grid.Column width={5}>
                  <Icon name='plane' size={'big'} color={'green'}/>
                  {startLocation && startLocation.description}
              </Grid.Column>
            ...
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  I want to store ratingsAverage to the component state, If I did that inside the componentDidUpdate(), It would cause Maximum update depth exceeded error. Do you have any idea to do this?

Comment: @KyleZhang Why are you storing your props in the state? It is an anti-pattern. You should use your props directly instead, rather than caching a value. You should read it: https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e

Comment: Beacuse in my child compoent, I am using Rating from material-ui, inside the Rating component I need to put a value. If I directly use ratingsAverage for Rating's value like this: <Rating readOnly value={ratingsAverage} precision={0.5} size={'large'}/>. Then the value of the rating won't show up, so I want to try store ratingsAverage to state and then use the state as the value for Rating. Do you know how to directly use ratingsAverage as value of the Rating?

Comment: @KyleZhang you should try ```<Rating readOnly value={ratingsAverage ? ratingsAverage : 0} precision={0.5} size={'large'}/>```